# Avoid for-loop to increase performance

Tags: matlab, performance, for-loop, optimization

**Is it possible to obtain the matrix `A` in a more efficient way than using a for loop?**

```
a = 6;  % constant
b = 2;  % constant
s = 0.1; % possible to change
I = 12; % possible to change

A = zeros(a,I+1);    
A(:,1) = rand(a,1); % some initial value 
B = rand(b,I);

% possible to avoid for-loop to increase performance?
for i = 1:I
    A(:,i+1) = fun(A(:,i),B(:,i), a, s);
end
```

The function fun is given as

```
function [AOut] = fun(AIn, B, a, s)
    AOut = zeros(a,1);
    AOut(1) = AIn(1) + AIn(4)*s*cos(AIn(3));
    AOut(2) = AIn(2) + AIn(4)*s*sin(AIn(3));
    AOut(3) = AIn(3) + AIn(4)*AIn(6)*s;
    AOut(4) = AIn(4) + AIn(5)*s;
    AOut(5) = AIn(5) + B(1);
    AOut(6) = AIn(6) + B(2);
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i dont think you can optimize the loop in regards to effiency as the last values are needed for calculating the next. @Tony Tannous showed you a nice way how to get rid of the loop in your code. For better performance at high values of `I`  you can change fun() to:

```
function [AOut] = fun2(AIn, B, a, s)

    AOut=AIn+  [AIn(4)*s*cos(AIn(3)) ;...
                AIn(4)*s*sin(AIn(3)) ;...
                AIn(4)*AIn(6)*s ;...
                AIn(5)*s ; ...
                B(1) ; ...
                B(2)];
end
```

Comment: Thanks for the hint I'll implement it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if `a != n`

You will get an error:

> Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

So you must be cautious

And, to get rid of the loop you can do this:

EDIT:
Apparently i isn't getting modified on the right side. I'll try to fix it and reedit my answer.

anyway, to get rid of the loop you can still use `A(:, i:1:I)`

```
i = 1;
A(:, i:1:I) = fun(A(:,i),B(:,i), a, s);
```

If you have any further question, please ask!

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution I'll try it this way. Sorry the `n` is a mistake it should be `a`. I'll edit my post.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. I keep getting the error:
`Assignment has fewer non-singleton rhs dimensions than non-singleton subscripts`

Comment: @evolved, it is because the matrix can't store float and double... you are assigning a number which is not double.

Comment: Isn't it because the rhs `fun(A(:,i),B(:,i), a, s)` is a vector and the lhs `A(:, i:1:I)` is a matrix?

Comment: Well, you can try transpose the vector from fun. Aout = Aout.';

Comment: This is not working since the size of the rhs `AOut` is 6x1 and the size of the lhs is 6xI = 6x12. Can you run the code with no error?